# How to add stored procedure parameter without knowing parameter datatype?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am using SQL Server and want to update value of specific cell with stored procedure. I will use parameters to find right table, column, row and new value for cell. Cell/Value can be different datatype on different times. How to create stored procedure parameter without giving knowing the datatype of parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use data type  [sql_variant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/sql-variant-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```
DECLARE @v1 sql_variant;  
SET @v1 = 'ABC';  
SELECT @v1;  
SELECT SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@v1, 'BaseType');  
SELECT SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@v1, 'MaxLength');
```

upd:
Datatype from the cell not needed

```
DECLARE @a TABLE 
(
    i int,
    s varchar(100),
    m money
)
INSERT INTO @a VALUES (1,'ss', pi())

DECLARE @v sql_variant

SELECT @v = i FROM @a
SELECT SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@v, 'BaseType');  

SELECT @v = s FROM @a
SELECT SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@v, 'BaseType');  

SELECT @v = m FROM @a
SELECT SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@v, 'BaseType');
```

Comment: This seems to work otherwise but I need to convert the "@v1" to datatype from the cell. Subquerying from the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS doesn't work on CONVERT because it expects datatype and not this subquery result. Got any advice for that?